# How do you disallow root in robots.txt, but allow a subdirectory?

Tags: robots.txt

Using robots.txt, how do you disallow the root of a site (http://www.example.com/) but allow a subdirectory (http://www.example.com/lessons/)?

Answer (score 6):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: /lessons/
Allow: /other-dir/
```

This does disallow the entire website, but explicitly allows given directories.

Comment: You should be careful with this as "Allow" is an unofficial 'extension' to the robots.txt standard. All the major search engines support it I believe, but minor ones or other services may not and ignore the entire site.

Comment: and you need to put the Allow first than the Disallow

Answer (score 2):

You must list the Allow lines first as the file is read on first match basis.

> To evaluate if access to a URL is allowed, a robot must attempt to
>      match the paths in Allow and Disallow lines against the URL, in the
>      order they occur in the record. The first match found is used. If no
>      match is found, the default assumption is that the URL is allowed.

Reference:
http://www.robotstxt.org/norobots-rfc.txt

Google provides a tool in webmaster tools for testing your file. I always recommend testing your file.  See "Test a site's robots.txt file:" near bottom.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449